# Matlab RMI error in function contains at startup and during runtime

Tags: matlab, rmi

In the last couple days (since changing from Matlab 2017a pre-release to Matlab R2017a) I have been getting an error message when starting up Matlab, which states that the function or variable 'isTextStrict' is undefined:

[image: start-up error]

Something similar occurs when actually calling the function `contains`, as for example in this small code snippet:

```
contains('test','test')
```

which throws the error

Undefined function or variable 'isTextStrict'.
Error in contains (line 37)
    if ~isTextStrict(s)

And similarly:
[image]

Has anyone seen this problem before? This did not occur previously.
I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I've not installed R2017b yet so not seen it. However in R2016b the function _contains_ line 37 is  "if ~ischar(s) && ~iscellstr(s) && ~isstring(s)", so looks like _contains_ was changed and 'isTextStrict' was introduced at R2017a. It might be worth doing a clean install of R2017a and/or search for the isTextStrict function and check it's in your Matlab path.

Comment: @Adrian: Reinstalling Matlab did indeed do the job. I wonder what went wrong during the install. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and reinstalling (after deleting both the problematic installation of R2017a and the pre-release version) solved the problem. I think I had left an open instance of the pre-release version when installing the R2017a, so that may be the problem.